# Unable to find "startxref" keyword opening PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I am downloading a file, saving it locally and then opening it to get the number of pages in the file. I am getting an error: `Unable to find "startxref" keyword.` I have done searches and not found anything that could be connected to my problem.

```
public function getPageCountPDF($jobid) {
    $this->load->library('Awss3', null, 'S3');
    require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdf.php';
    require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdi.php';
    $PdfTranscriptInfo = $this->MJob->getDOCCSPdfTranscript($jobid);
    $filename = $PdfTranscriptInfo['origfilename'];
    $PdfFilename = 'uploads/' . $jobid . '/' . $filename;
    $pdfdata = $this->S3->readfile($PdfFilename, false, 'bucket');
    $localfilename = FCPATH . 'tmp/local.pdf'; 
    fopen($localfilename, 'a');
    $pdf = new FPDI();
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($localfilename);  
    unlink($localfilename);
    return $pageCount;
}
```

When I echo out the $pdfdata, I see the startxref keyword, so why is it not finding it?

Anyone? Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I checked if the file is compressed and it is not.

**SECOND EDIT:** I see that my PDF is version 1.3, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: It's difficult to debug this without knowing which S3 library you're using. For example I can't tell exactly what `$this->S3->readfile` does.

Comment: @SamTolton, it reads the file from S3, where it is stored. If I echo $pdfdata, it displays the following: `%PDF-1.3
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (��0322Byer Frantz)
/Producer (Amyuni PDF Converter version 4.5.0.5)
/CreationDate (D:20180507112129-04'00')
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Length 8 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x��Z�r�6��g:�q; K��o�L�jmɕ����EUWm"���N��,@K`cO_2>�b�rq��I%�_�E\����d��dI�ET�*.�(Mb�Le\Uѱ���v��"�?�(/cYEE����x�#*��@��F{/�"GX��{�N����TDQ�����yۏ�$Nd�6���������M��5i��/j�21A��2� tH��D� d�>5B��]�p�����y�q)zY'"����U2��,B�k���Y�ǋH�8�S��C{��
���

Comment: Then I think you may be missing a step as you're loading the PDF from `FCPATH . 'tmp/local.pdf';` but I can't see where you're outputting `$pdfdata` to that file. You probably need to `file_put_contents (FCPATH . 'tmp/local.pdf'; $pdfdata);` after reading the file from S3.

Comment: @SamTolton, okay, thank you. I will try that and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: @SamTolton, I am now getting a unlink(C:\wamp64\www\companyname\tmp/local.pdf): Permission denied error. I thank you for your help so far. Will continue to work on this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @SamTolton. His answer helped me solve the problem.  Here is my code now that works:

```
public function getPageCountPDF($jobid) {
    $this->load->library('Awss3', null, 'S3');
    require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdf.php';
    require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdi.php';
    $PdfTranscriptInfo = $this->MJob->getDOCCSPdfTranscript($jobid);
    $filename = $PdfTranscriptInfo['origfilename'];
    $PdfFilename = 'uploads/' . $jobid . '/' . $filename;
    $pdfdata = $this->S3->readfile($PdfFilename, false, 'bucket');
    $localfilename = FCPATH . 'tmp/local.pdf';
    file_put_contents($localfilename, $pdfdata);
    $pdf = new FPDI();
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($localfilename);
    $pdf->cleanUp();
    unlink($localfilename);
    return $pageCount;
}
```